# 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location

Tags: c++

I have this function for reading text from files:

```
uintmax_t ResourcePack::getText(const string& file, char** data)
{
    *data = new char[static_cast<size_t>(size) + 1];
    fseek(_fileDescriptor, static_cast<long>(begin), SEEK_SET);
    fread(*data, static_cast<size_t>(size), 1, _fileDescriptor);
    *data[size] = '\0';
}
```

`FILE* _fileDescriptor, uintmax_t size` and `uintmax_t begin` are get in other code, not important here, but with correct values.

`fseek` and `fread` lines work fine.
Actually, I have the file content in *data, but when the last line is executed, I got the access violation.

Why I can write into `*data` using `fread`, but not `using *data[size] = '\0'`?

Comment: Operator precedence - you want `(*data)[size]`, not `*data[size]`.

Comment: As @PaulR said...  Generally I prefer to store a temporary `char*` variable and work with that in a function, then store it via the `char**` prior to returning.  That way I avoid the extra syntax guff that can lead to errors and/or sore eyes. =)

Comment: 0xCC means you've read [uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having problems with operator precedence - you want `(*data)[size]`, not `*data[size]`.

Comment: arg nice! 
I forgot that!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the precedence of operators `*` and `[]`. `*data[size]` means to access the nth `char*` in data, and then dereference its first character, not to get the nth character of the array pointed to by `data`.

You want `(*data)[size]` instead to perform the operations in the correct order.

EDIT: Since this is C++ you'd be better off using `char*&` to eliminate these sorts of problems, or *much* better off using `vector` and letting the standard library manage your memory for you!

Comment: I usually use std containers, but for this situation, a raw pointer is better in my case ;)
I just forgot operators precedence :P